# What's the maximum mouse buttons a mouse can have?

Tags: mouse

hey there guys i need your help i'm making a game engine and i don't know what to put as the maximum amount of mouse buttons you can use. Meaning how many mouse buttons can have?

Mouse button:
For example the right or left mouse button or the middle mouse button

Comment: I suppose they are only limited by real estate of the mouse itself. Take for example one of [Razer's offerings](http://www.amazon.com/Razer-Chroma-Multi-Color-Wireless-Gaming/dp/B00NW6T6CC?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAJ2RTWSYJUOAO3DIA&tag=bom_tomsguide-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00NW6T6CC&tzd=21&ascsubtag=[site|tguus[cat|[art|[pid|B00NW6T6CC[tid|14626412919241668[bbc|LESPRIX) which has at least 14 buttons.

Comment: I think opengl has a fixed amount of MouseButtons it can handle. Maybe hold on to that number.

Comment: @n247s: OpenGL does not handle input at all, so there is no limit imposed from this side.

Comment: it has to do with glfw

Comment: Wich is part of the opengl library I thought.

Comment: nope its in fact not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [USB HID standard](https://www.usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111) ([page 61](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1CDO.png)) allocates bits for three buttons. But there is also a four-bit value that is device-specific. If treated as a four-bit number instead of four discrete flags, then you can have up to fifteen additional buttons.

---

[image: page 61]

Comment: Interesting. Mouses with large numbers of buttons (for gaming) tend to map them to keyboard events, not mouse. I would guess this is because high number mouse buttons are unusual and therefore lack software support.

Comment: If the extra bits are treated that way, wouldn't it make it impossible to register simultaneous clicks of multiple mouse buttons?  In any case, it looks like 7 mouse buttons should be possible, without encountering that problem.  I can't seem to find any such mice available, though.  (https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9495/7888)

Comment: And yet a 20 button mouse exists: [please help me, I'm in hell](https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Gaming-Backlit-Programmable-Buttons/dp/B0086UK7IQ#:~:text=For%20complete%20control%20in%20your,for%20mastering%20your%20favorite%20MMOs.).

Answer (score 0):

An Asus gaming mouse had 31 keys !
I am not sure if this is the maximum, but 31 does sound like a lot!